# Finding a formula for an inverse square field in terms of a position of object in field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

Say we have:

$ F(x,y) = \dfrac{ϵq_1q_2}{|r|^2} \hat{u}$

I am attempting to find the formula in terms of the position of the charge $q_2$ in $(x,y)$, while leaving everything else constant. (thanks Peter!)

I have come up with:

$ F(x,y) = \dfrac{ϵq_1q_2}{x^2+y^2}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat{i} + \dfrac{ϵq_1q_2}{x^2+y^2}\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat{j}$

I also am considering:

$ F(x,y) = \dfrac{ϵq_1x}{x^2+y^2}\hat{i} + \dfrac{ϵq_1y}{x^2+y^2}\hat{j}$

Ultimately I will be finding the divergence and testing if the field is conservative.

Comment: Presumably the second $\hat{i}$ should be a $\hat{j}$ in the last two formulas? Also note that $\epsilon$ has a specific conventional meaning in this context, and it is not the meaning you have given it.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that. Also, I'm aware, but for this application, it's treated as an arbitrary constant.

Comment: The second equation is wrong. The divergence of the first equation is a singular delta function, which is hard to get in Cartesian coordinates